# Expected value of a ticket

Tags: probability, statistics

one thousand tickets are sold at $1$ each.
 one ticket will be randomly selected and the winner will receive a color television valued at $391$. 
What is the expected value for a person that buys one ticket

Comment: Could you find $P(\text{you win the TV})$? How about $P(\text{you don't win the TV})$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of expected value? You just need to plug the values to the formula and you get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Expected Value of 1 ticket = 391/1000 = 0.391

This can be interpreted in the following way:

Out of 1000 times when you buy a ticket, you are only expected to win 1 time with a reward worth 391. And in all the 999 other cases, you are not expected to win anything.

Thus you are expected to get 391 when you invest 1000. So your expectation is 0.391